# silverlight business application - mysql/net 6.5.4 connector - object reference not set

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I have created a new silverlight business application. I have added mysql.data, mysql.web, mysql.data.entity dll's of version 6.5.4 mysql/net connector. I built the solution. Then I got the blue icon, where i can configure connector to mysql db for role providers and connection string. but thats not happening. When I clicked the icon, I am getting error saying "Object reference not set to instance of object" What could be the problem? KIndly help me with workaround
MY ENVIRONMENT

VS2010, Silverlight4, silverlight toolkit APR2010, mysql server installed, mysql connector 6.5.4, Windows 7 64bit.

thanks

EDIT 1:: all the connectors are added to silverlight host web application, but not to silverlight application directly.
All the connector dll's are added to the host application to consume in web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uff.... some relief.

I made a mistake. We should click the blue icon of net/mysql connector in the solution explorer, after selecting the web hosting project but not the actual silverlight project.

This is working only with few of my solutions though.

Edit:: 
Working fine. I completely messed up web.config of both silverlight application and web hosting project.  Cleaned the code, removed the references, added them again. Now, the mysql connector wizard works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight project (due to re-written .NET code specially for Silverlight) you can reference **only** projects/DLL compiled for Silverlight or created in Silverlight. It's not possible for now (and I personally think it never will) to reference event regular .NET 4/3/2 project from Silverlight project. There's only one exception - is Portable Library projects.

I'm not aware of any MySql Connector that written specially for SL - it must be regular .NET project that could be used in normal .NET application - but Silverlight it's different story...

Usually when you need to gain access to Database or out-of-Silverlight enviroment (xap) file - you need to use WCF services (prefered solution) or somehow find the Silverlight Storage location (the only place on hard disk that Silverlight have access to)

Comment: Hi Jasper, thanks for the inputs. I have added the connector dlls to the hosting web application but not to the silverlight application directly.

Comment: the wizard for the mysql connection strings is not opening. I am trying to put the role providers, connection strings manually as of now, for consuming in web services. But using wizard makes them easy, so trying for the wizard, which is giving this OBJECT REFERENCE NOt SET ERROR

Comment: You can read here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ about connection strings for various platforms